# How do I find the power of complex number $(1+i\sqrt{3})^3$ without using inverse trig functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the following

$$(1+i\sqrt{3})^3$$

I know that:

$$z^n=r^n(\cos(n\varphi)+i\sin(n\varphi))$$

$r$ in my case equals to $$r=\sqrt{1+3}=\sqrt{4} = 2 \rightarrow 2^3=8$$

where I am stuck is an argument of complex number, the main problen is that our tutor $\textbf{does not permit}$ using $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$ so I have to find $\cos\varphi$ and $\sin\varphi$ separately, what I wrote was:

$$\varphi = \begin{cases} \cos\varphi = \frac{1}{2} \\ \sin\varphi = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \end{cases}$$

If I know solutions (they are trivial as well), how should I proceed?

Comment: The sine is $\sqrt 3/2$. The angle $\varphi$ is a very well-known one.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, yea, I am more confused how to convert it to the proper argument, equations are out of discussion :)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I mean if we are permitted using $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$ that is not a problem at all, if we have $\sin$ and $\cos$ values separately I do not know how to conver it into the argument

Comment: Use the binomial theorem.

Comment: @M.Mass What kind of teacher does not permit the use of $\arctan$ but 
permit the use of polar coordinates and De-Moivre's theorem, did you ask him why $\arctan$ is not permitted ?

Comment: Is it possible that you misunderstood about $\arctan$? In particular, you may have just been saying "the arctangent is $\pi/3$ so that's the angular position", but in reality that only tells you the angular position is either $\pi/3$ or $4\pi/3$ and you still have to do (very slightly) more work to figure out which, and the tutor was admonishing you for not doing that additional work.

Comment: @Hurkyl, well, i remember something like "solve it separately for the start, because otherwise my experience tells me you will miss $\textrm{arg} $ value"

Answer (score 3):

If your tutor doesn't allow use of $$\tan^{-1}$$ , then probably he doesn't expect you to use it.

We could very well solve it by expansion

> $$(1+\sqrt{3}i)^3$$$$1+3\sqrt{3}i+3×3i^2+3\sqrt{3}i^3$$$$1+3\sqrt{3}i-9-3\sqrt{3}i$$$$-8$$It is much easier this way.

Comment: the result should be -8, you forgot your 3's in the cubic expansion

Comment: Oh thanks btw @orangeskid